# Install Certificates on iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate

Firstly, forgive my ignorance in this subject - I'm still reading up on it.

We're using a 3rd party library to play DRM protected videos, and we need to install a certificate.der file at some point.

This is installed into Settings > Profiles. But when we install it, it reads that it is "not trusted". You then get a warning that it is not trusted when you click install, but then when you click install again, it becomes trusted (because you have explicity trusted it).

What steps do I need to take to make the certificate.der file read 'trusted' right from the start? Do I need to get it 'signed' by an authority? Can I somehow sign it myself?

Any tips would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it has to be signed by a trusted CA. afaik you cant install add. root CAs on the iphone so get a trusted certificate

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can add trusted root certificates to iOS Devices by using a MDM Server or the iPhone Configuration Utility http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465 .

Alternatively, the user can manually install a trusted CA via email or Safari.

Comment: Care to elaborate how you host a certificate and install it through Safari?

Comment: Spot on, I just succeeded in doing this with the following guide: http://wiki.cylonmobile.com/home/add-ca-certification-authority-to-iphone